# How to schedule execution of sharepoint workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Does Sharepoint 2013 provide a native solution for workflow scheduling?

I know **HarePoint Workflow Scheduler** as alternative solution, but I would like to know if the new Sharepoint 2013 capabilities include this feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a task scheduling tool such as SQL Server Agent or Windows Task Scheduler and have that execute a PowerShell script that start the workflow.

Here's an example: http://www.thesysadminhimself.com/2013/09/sharepoint-start-workflow-all-items-powershell.html

Answer (score 2):

[SharePoint Workflow Scheduler](http://plumsail.com/workflow-scheduler/) developed by my team supports SharePoint 2013 workflows as well as SharePoint 2010 workflows.

It has friendly scheduling interface and additionally supports cron syntax to create extremely complex schedules.

See documentation:

- [How to schedule workflow](http://plumsail.com/workflow-scheduler/docs/schedule-workflow/)
- [How to create advanced schedule using *cron* syntax](http://plumsail.com/workflow-scheduler/docs/advanced-schedule-cron-syntax/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know SharePoint 2013 doesn't have a native solution for workflow scheduling. From the top of my head however I can suggest the following approaches:

1. Create a SharePoint Timer Job which will trigger your workflow based on the schedule you provided.
2. Create a console application using the workflow services to trigger the workflow manually. Once this is done, setup a scheduled task based on the schedule you wanted it to run.
3. A blog post shown [here](http://sharepointgypsy.blogspot.com/2011/01/sharepoint-designer-workflows-3.html) demonstrates how to have a workflow run once a day.

Comment: I would like to try the new LOOP Feature to do it. It works, but I can't check date time values as I would like to do.

Comment: You mean you want to have a workflow which utilizes the loop function? What date time values would you like to check?

Comment: I thought that loop would be useful for me. But now I've got the right solution. Instead of schedule an execution, I used an action to stop execution until and specific date and time. It works like scheduling, because I stop the workflow in its first action. Now my doubt is, what happens if my application break down? If I restart my application, I will lose all my workflows running?

Comment: You will not loose your running workflows, but for SharePoint 2010 workflows it was not best practice to pause for delay. It affects performance, I assume that for SharePoint 2013 workflows it can be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Expiration Policy found in the Information management policy settings in Permissions and managements. This will allow you to set up a timed, recurring workflow. Not sure is this is the type of workflow you would like to set up. I found the information here: http://blogs.askcts.com/2013/05/14/creating-a-timed-workflow-in-sharepoint-2010/

It answers the question for Sharepoint 2010, but also works for Sharepoint 2013